# How can i change the background of my App after it approved and already in App Store

Tags: api, swift, parse-platform, xcode6, background-image

I am new in Xcode and IOS development.
i have designed and finished my app and i connected with Parse for push notification and core data.

the problem is what i didn't understand is: if in future i want to change the background of my app or add new event or to change the palace of button my app, how can i do that? i have to rebuild and submit it again or there is any way to do by online a website like parse?

i couldn't find the answer any where, help please...

Thanks ,

Comment: Yes every change has to be resubmitted and approved.

Comment: even if i want to add some event every week for my company?

Answer (score 1):

If you had designed your app to load the background data from Parse, then you could just put the new background on Parse and your app would load it.  There is no need to submit a new app to do that.  If you did it this way, you'd want to have a default background in the case when the network is not available.

You can't add new code to your application with this method (that is not allowed), but you can add data such as images, text, etc.  The key point here is that you have to design your app from the start to work this way, then it is simply a matter of putting the new data on Parse where your app can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @vacawama's very good answer:

For this version you are out of luck, since it sounds like you did not design it to use a background that is loaded from your Parse server.

What you need to do is to code an update to your app that has these new abilities, and submit that to the app store. Once that version is approved then you should be able to change the background from the server.

Comment: Thanks, in parse server where i can find the code or connect it with that, i found the core data and push notification but the rest i dont know where is it? can you help me with that?

Comment: This is new development. There i no "where is it." You need to design this feature (both server and iOS code) and implement it yourself.

Comment: you mean, i have to write the code there is no sample code?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.